# Using BCS to retrieve data using multiple possible accounts

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, bcs

We have a third party application we need to connect to using BCS to display info in our SharePoint 2010 Intranet. The third party application exposes web services we can consume to get the information. However, it only allows 5 simultaneous sessions for each set of credentials. The problem might arise on production where 60 users might connect simultaneously so we would need 12 sets of credentials from the third party application since we will connect with pre-determined credentials from the app, and not with the user identity.
I am considering the possible authentication approaches to follow. One option is to write a Windows application that will take each 5 users and map them to one set of credentials from the third party app within BCS. This way, whenever a user is attempting to connect, we are sure they will not be kicked out since they share the credentials with only 4 other people. But at the same time, we have to map each user that will be added to our company in the future.
The second option would be to keep it dynamic. When the user is attempting to connect, we check to see which set of credentials has less than five sessions open and then use that. While this seems to require less future maintenance, I am not sure it is feasible.
Any suggestions about how I should proceed?
Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't everyone have unique permissions?  It sounds like you are trying to bypassing licensing restrictions, is that correct?  If so, I don't think you can get assistance from this community.

Comment: It sounds like you've purchased a 12-user license and are attempting to stretch it to 60 users.  If this is legitimate, you should ask the 3rd party company what they recommend in situations like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Licensing issues aside, looking just at the technical issue, I would connect the BCS to a web service or .net code and let it manage the connection pooling. This seems to be a poor work around though to get passed account issues.